# ArrayFormula() List of Dynamic Sums from Indirectly Referenced Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, excel-indirect

I have a problem that I cannot seem to figure out a solution to using Google Sheets. I need to generate a list of partial sums using data that is sorted but the size of the input range is undetermined. The size of the partial sum range is likewise undetermined.

I know how to do this in AppScript. However, I seem to run into issues loading the function and my calculations slow down because of it. So I would like to find a solution that uses formulas.

Here is a sample of the data I am working with: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HCCM2sJ3lwIjLBUIKbaSFyUVKexXOSKkNmxp4bSd0xA/edit?usp=sharing

I included both the original sample input and expected result and what I am trying to work with now, using a list of generated indirect ranges.

Another way to look at the problem would be: I want to group the data but keep the general integrity of the list intact; reduce redundancies in the list.

Does anyone have any ideas for a more complete solution using only Google Sheet formulas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=sum(indirect(B2))
```

and drag down.

Edit:
One formula solution (to be entered in row 2):

`=ArrayFormula(MMult(--IF((transpose(row(indirect("A2:A"&max(--RegexExtract(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),":.*?(\d+)")))))<--RegexExtract(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),"(\d+):"))+(transpose(row(indirect("A2:A"&max(--RegexExtract(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),":.*?(\d+)")))))>--RegexExtract(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),":.*?(\d+)")),,transpose(indirect("A2:A"&max(--RegexExtract(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),":.*?(\d+)"))))),row(indirect("A2:A"&max(--RegexExtract(Filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""),":.*?(\d+)"))))^0))`

Comment: That won't work as my input data is not static. The sample data is, but I could end up 100, 1586, 10482, 12, etc. I would not know the size in the final sheet.

Comment: I'm not following. What do you mean by "I would not know the size in the final sheet"? Are you referring to the size of the Data column, namely column A? Why wouldn't the formula I provided work for different sizes?

Comment: In my final sheet I will not be able to control how big the Data column (column A) will be and I will not be monitoring the sheet enough to keep pasting in more and more rows. The usage case could be 1000 rows or much much more. I would prefer my final sheet to be scalable (as scalable as a Google Sheet can be anyhow).

Comment: That said, I noticed your edit and thank you for providing it. I did not consider using a regex like that. Thank you.